# Is choosing 'Security Updates Only' on installation of Ubuntu Server enough?

Tags: server, apt, updates, security

I want necessary security updates on my Ubuntu servers, without my interference. **In general, do I need to do anything else after selecting the 'Security updates only' option in the automatic updates section of the OS installation process?**

I've looked in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` and seen that the only archive available is indeed security. I'll probably set up the `Unattended-Upgrade::Mail` and `Unattended-Upgrade::MailOnlyOnError` parameters, and choose to reboot at a more convenient time with `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00"`.

I've looked at the documentation for [unattended-upgrades on 14.04 server](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html), which I understand is for setting it up after installation. The guide suggests the following in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

But my version of this file only contains:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
```

Apart from the `APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval` which I understand, are these only different because I have a `50unattended-upgrades` file?

Answer (score 2):

In normal cases where you want a stable deployment of lets say LAMP and all what comes with it in production environment security updates are sufficient.

You need to change the

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`

file to this:

```
# switches on the apt get update run 0 for off
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
# lets the server pre download available packages 0 for off
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
# runs apt-get clean every 7 days
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
# switches the unattended upgrades on 0 for off
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

Beside that you have a couple more options in the

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` file.

P.S.: all other upgrades are normally done on a server environment by hand.